# Can I filter an Xpages search bar

Tags: xpages

I have been given an XPages project which I did not develop.  The project has a OneUILayout that includes a Search Bar "facet".  Is it possible to code a filter into the search bar facet so that retrieved records are omitted that have a field with a certain value.  I have very little experience with XPages.  The search results are output to a OneUI_searchpage.xsp where an edit box displays the search string then a dynamic View Panel shown the retrieved records.  I have attached the source code for these two items below.  Thank you

```
<xp:label value="Search String:" id="label1"></xp:label>
   <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{param.search}"></xp:inputText>
      <xp:panel id="maincontentpanel">
         <xe:dynamicViewPanel rows="30" id="dynamicViewPanel1"    
            width="100%">
              <xe:this.data>
                 <xp:dominoView viewName="ContractsFlatByYear"  
                    var="view">
                    <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:return  
                        param.search;}]]></xp:this.search>
                 </xp:dominoView>
             </xe:this.data>
       </xe:dynamicViewPanel>
```

After some consultation with stwissel below, I amended the application to have a check box on the search results xpage with it checked by default and created an additional view for the same output.  One view to show cancelled contracts and one to omit cancelled contracts.  The relevant Xpage section now looks like as follows;

```
<xp:checkBox text="Omit Cancelled Contracts"
  id="OmitCancelled" defaultChecked="true" checkedValue="True"
  uncheckedValue="False" style="padding-left:5.0em" value="# 
    {viewScope.viewSel}">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" 
     refreshId="dynamicViewPanel1"></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:checkBox>
<xp:panel id="maincontentpanel">
   <xe:dynamicViewPanel rows="30" id="dynamicViewPanel1"
        width="100%" partialRefresh="true">
     <xe:this.data>
       <xp:dominoView var="view">
         <xp:this.viewName>
           <![CDATA[#{javascript:var cancelledYesNo = viewScope.viewSel 
                = getComponent("OmitCancelled").getValue();
               if(cancelledYesNo == "True"){
                  viewName = "ContractsFlatByYear"}
              else {
                viewName = "ContractsFlatByYearandCancelled"}}]]>
        </xp:this.viewName>
     <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:return param.search;}]] 
       ></xp:this.search>
   </xp:dominoView>
 </xe:this.data>
</xe:dynamicViewPanel>
```

This appears to work but I have the check box onChange event to apply a partial refresh on the dynamicviewpanel but only refreshes when I click on the dynamicviewpanel itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search bar facet only captures what you want to search and sends it to the specified XPages for processing.

You have 2 options:

- Alter the facet to send the additional condition to the search page
- Alter the search function in the search page (the one the query gets posted to) to filter that (if it is static).

Be aware: filtering in code is **not** a security feature (in case you were intending that). There's reader and author fields for that.

XPages in its core is JSF with some specialities around Domino. You might want to check out my [article series](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2013/12/domino-development-back-to-basics-overview.html) on them.

**Update**

Based on the code snippet, your can get the desired result quite fast. Edit the view selection formula and add  `& conContractStatus <> "cancelled"`. You need to check first if that view is used elsewhere to show canceled contracts too. If that is the case, copy the view (eg add Active behind the name) and make the changes there.

**Update 2**

Your code doesn't return a value and you don't need to get to the component

```
 <xp:this.viewName>
       <![CDATA[#{javascript:return (viewScope.viewSel=="True") ? "ContractsFlatByYear" : "ContractsFlatByYearandCancelled";}]]>
    </xp:this.viewName>
```

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  So "facets" cannot really be altered, is that correct?  I will have a look at your two options and see what I can do.  Basically the records are Contracts with a field of conContractStatus and I want to omit the ones that are conContractStatus = Cancelled

Comment: You can alter the content of a facet. But your case might be actually MUCH simpler. Check the code that does the search: could be db.ftsearch or view.ftsearch in the later case just alter the view selection formula, in the former switch to a view search. Btw. If you post a code sample answers are less guesswork

Comment: I have added some source code for search output page.  Still looking

Comment: Might be faster to fix than you expect

Comment: I am assuming its something to do with the javascript:return param.search part.

Comment: I may have this working but not sure if this was the best way to do this. Code above says view ContractsFlatByYear. So looked at this View and in the "View Selection" object I changed - SELECT ((Form = "Contract")) & (initialstagecomplete = "1") to SELECT ((Form = "Contract")) & (initialstagecomplete = "1") & conContractStatus != "Cancelled". Now when I cancel a contract and perform a search with the same search string the cancelled contract is not returned

Comment: As long as the view isn't used anywhere else where it is supposed to show canceled contracts, you found the fastest way

Comment: Thought I had this completed but application administrator has just changed goal post. Now wants an option for the search to include Cancelled Contracts. I can add a check box and set a partial refresh on the dynamic view panel. Just have to figure out how to amend the view or output if check box is unchecked (default checked is true)

Comment: Add a view that shows all and compute the name of the view based on the parameter. Btw feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Thanks stwissel.  It appears to be working after I emended the code as above but the partial refresh is not working.  I have tried a full refresh but the same thing happens

Comment: Bind the checkbox to a scope variable (viewScope seems appropriate ) and check the variable, not the control.

Comment: I can bind the checkbox to a scope variable easy enough in the checkbox data properties in the interface by calling the variable viewSel but I cannot seem to be able to access its value in the javascript condition.  Everything I try gives an error when I run the application

Comment: What code? Update your question with the code that throws an error and the error message.  Switch on standard error handler, so you get a useful message and not just 500

Comment: Thanks for patience.  I have amended the code.  It now is not showing an error but the refresh issue still remains. I realise the current code of var cancelledYesNo has tow equals in the line but that was the only way I could get it to attempt to retrieve the viewScope value and not get an error.  The errors were that it didn't recognise the viewScope variable.  Foe example if I used this below it did not recognise the cancelledYesNo variable value; var cancelledYesNo = viewScope.viewSel.value();

Comment: In JavaScript "=" is a value assignment, not a comparison. Comparison is "==" or "==="

Comment: Thanks again.  I tried <![CDATA[#{javascript:return (viewScope.viewSel=="True") ? "ContractsFlatByYear" : "ContractsFlatByYearandCancelled";}]]>.  It runs but doesn't refresh when the check box is unchecked and still have to click somewhere on the page.  Also this makes the initial view use the cancelled view even with the check box checked and when I first uncheck the check box the view remains the same.  Strange when the first option after the ? symbol is "ContractsFlatByYear"

Comment: As this is beginning to seem a strange issue I am wondering if there is an alternative.  Such as the onChange event trigger another event to refresh the whole Xpage in the background and not rely on a partial refresh.  I might look into that option

Comment: You need to include the checkbox into the part that you refresh... But you might solve it actually differently. When a user actually searches, you open a new page, so it might be easier to add a parameter to the URL and look for that one to determine the view to use